# Best practice for Spark to read kafka streams with schema registry (avro)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Is there any best practice for Spark to process kafka stream which is serialized in Avro with schema registry? Especially for Spark Structured Streams?

I have found an example at https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/spark-kafka-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/scalac/spark/AvroConsumer.scala . But I have failed to load `AvroConverter` class. I cannot find artifact named `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer` in mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Confluent repo in your `build.sbt`:

```
val repositories = Seq(
  "confluent" at "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/",
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
)
```

See: https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/spark-kafka-avro/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: I guess `--repositories http://packages.confluent.io/maven/` should work

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer.
I have one more question. If I want to add it when I use spark-submit with --repositories option, how can I make a URI for confluent repository?

Comment: `--repositories http://packages.confluent.io/maven/` works! Thank you. But, there would be conflict between `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11` and `confluent.io:kafka-avro-serializer`. Spark cannot find kafka.defaultSource when the option `--package org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 --repositories http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ --packages confluent.io:kafka-avro-serializer:1.0` is given

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to prepare a complete assembly where you handle dependency conflicts?

Comment: @Joo You should ideally be using a version of the serializer code much newer than 1.0... The latest release is `4.1.1`